# How to save intermediate weights when training a neural network

Tags: pointers, pytorch

I am training a neural network using pytorch, and I want to save the weights at every iteration. In other words, I want to create a list that contains all the weights the neural network has had during training.

I did the following:

```
for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):

     (.....code that is used to train the model here.....)

     weight = model.fc2.weight.detach().numpy()
     weights_list.append(weight)
```

When I then print the entries of the list 'weights_list', I notice that they are all the same, which cannot be true, because I have printed the weights during the training and they do change (and the network actually does learn, so they have to).
My guess is that every entry of the list is actually a pointer to the weights of the network at the moment the list is checked. So:

1) Is my guess correct?
2) How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality to save and load weights is built in. To save to a file you can use

```
torch.save('checkpoint.pt', model.state_dict())
```

and to load you can use

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('checkpoint.pt'))
```

---

That said, converting to numpy doesn't necessarily create a copy. For example if you have a numpy array `y` and want to create a copy you could use

```
x = numpy.copy(y)
```

Comment: Thanks!I'm having an extra problem here:
From here, how do I obtain an array with the weights contained in a single layer?

Comment: It depends on the model. Once you load the model you can access it's submodules as member variables. For example if you had a model defined `class MyModel(nn.Module): def __init__(self): ... self.layer1 = nn.Linear(1,10) ...` (ignoring whitespace errors). Supposing an instance is defined as `model = MyModel()` you could access the weights as `model.layer1.weight` and `model.layer1.bias`. Alternatively if you've loaded the `'checkpoint.pt'` described here you could get the weights as `state_dict = torch.load('checkpoint.pt')` then `state_dict['layer1.weight']` and `state_dict['layer1.bias']`.

Comment: Using the `state_dict` variable in your previous comment. When in doubt you can `print(state_dict.keys())` and find the dictionary keys for the particular layers you're interested in (in the previous example they were `'layer1.weight'` and `'layer1.bias'`).